Fast AI Siamese model not improving
So I was following this tutorial: Fast Ai Siamese, however after I completed it, I got 50% accuracy. I tried loads of things, but nothing worked. So the only place where I think the problem could be is in the Siamese implementation itself, but I have little experience with fast.ai and no idea on how to fix it or where to even start. Maybe there is something obvious that I'm missing? Anyway, any comment helps. This is my code
class SiameseImage(fastuple):
    
    def show(self, ctx=None, **kwargs):
        if len(self) > 2:
            img1, img2, similarity = self
        else:
            img1, img2 = self
            similarity = 'Undetermined'

        if not isinstance(img1, Tensor):
            if img2.size != img1.size: img2 = img2.resize(img1.size)
            t1 = tensor(img1)
            t2 = tensor(img2)
            t1 = t1.permute(2,0,1)
            t2 = t2.permute(2,0,1)
        else:
            t1 = img1
            t2 = img2
        
        line = t1.new_zeros(t1.shape[0], t1.shape[1], 10)
        return show_image(torch.cat([t1, line, t2], dim=2), title = similarity, ctx=ctx, **kwargs) 


class ImageTuple(fastuple):
    
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, fns): return cls(tuple(PILImage.create(f) for f in fns))
    
    def show(self, ctx=None, **kwargs): 
        t1,t2 = self
        if not isinstance(t1, Tensor) or not isinstance(t2, Tensor) or t1.shape != t2.shape: return ctx
        line = t1.new_zeros(t1.shape[0], t1.shape[1], 10)
        return show_image(torch.cat([t1,line,t2], dim=2), ctx=ctx, **kwargs)
    

class SiameseModel(Module):
    
    def __init__(self, encoder, head):
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.head = head
    
    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        ftrs = torch.cat([self.encoder(x1), self.encoder(x2)], dim = 1)
        return self.head(ftrs)


class SiameseTransform(Transform):
    
    def __init__(self, files, splits, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.splbl2files = [{l: [f for f in files[splits[i]] if parent_label(f) == l] for l in labels}
                          for i in range(2)]
        self.valid = {f: self._draw(f,1) for f in files[splits[1]]}

    def encodes(self, f):
        f2,same = self.valid.get(f, self._draw(f,0))
        img1,img2 = PILImage.create(f),PILImage.create(f2)
        return SiameseImage(img1, img2, int(same))
    
    def _draw(self, f, split=0):
        same = random.random() < 0.5
        cls = parent_label(f)
        if not same: cls = random.choice(L(l for l in self.labels if l != cls)) 
        return random.choice(self.splbl2files[split][cls]),same


def get_x(t): return t[:2]
def get_y(t): return t[2]

def siamese_splitter(model):
    return [params(model.encoder), params(model.head)]

def loss_func(out, targ):
    return CrossEntropyLossFlat()(out, targ.long())

def train(dataset_path):
    files = get_image_files(dataset_path)
    
    labels = list(set(files.map(parent_label)))

    encoder = create_body(resnet50(), cut=-2)
    head = create_head(2048*2, 2, ps=0.5)
    model = SiameseModel(encoder, head)

    splits = RandomSplitter()(files)
    tfm = SiameseTransform(files, splits, labels)
    tls = TfmdLists(files, tfm, splits=splits)
    dls = tls.dataloaders(
        after_item=[Resize(256, method='squash'), ToTensor], 
        after_batch=[IntToFloatTensor, *aug_transforms(flip_vert=True, do_flip=True, max_rotate=50, max_warp=0.4, max_zoom=1.3), Normalize.from_stats(*imagenet_stats)],
        bs = 8
    )
    
    
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    learn = Learner(dls, model, loss_func=loss_func, splitter=siamese_splitter, metrics=accuracy)
    learn.fine_tune(
        epochs = 15,
        base_lr=2.51e-5,
        cbs=[SaveModelCallback(monitor='valid_loss'), EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor='valid_loss', patience=5)])
    learn.export('siamese1.pkl')

I tried changing batch size, different architectures, image sizes, epochs, various batch transformations and other things, but nothing changed, I always got 50% accuracy...
